# Letting media queries overwrite "regular" css

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to target old iPhones and desktop devices with media queries.

Would if be better to use one media query that overwrites the current css in case of a "phone" match:

```
body { color: red; }

@media (max-width:480px) {
    body { color: blue; }
}
```

Or is there any point of writing it like this:

```
@media (min-width:480px) {
    body { color: red; }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
    body { color: blue; }
}
```

Comment: It should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: @MehulMohan I'm not saying that it doesn't work - I just want to know if there's any difference between the two methods.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think that overriding is a problem? In your above example the results will be the same - the only difference is that by overriding you're saving a few bytes

Comment: @Danield What I'm mostly curious is about whether if #2 could "miss" any devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both methods work, I would use the first because using the first method:

1) Browsers which don't support media queries (ahem IE8) will at least have fallback styles

2) Your code is slightly smaller and less messy.

---

Also, for what it's worth (although not really related to your question) if you're interested in a mobile-first approach you could re-write the css as:

```
body { color: blue; }

@media (min-width:480px) {
    body { color: red; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mehul mentioned, both are okay, A simple google search brings you millions of resources. I found these two articles useful for mobile device web developing [iPhone CSS—tips for building iPhone websites](http://csswizardry.com/2010/01/iphone-css-tips-for-building-iphone-websites/) and [width versus device-width](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml), I hope they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay.

@media (max-width) would target every device under a specific resolution given and @media (min-width) would target every device above a specific resolution given.

Hope that helps.